# python bottle css image and css routing

Tags: python, python-2.7, bottle

How would I go about linking css and images to a template without routing it through bottle (`@route('/image/')` or `@route('/css/')`) and using a static_file return? because i am unable to link css normally (it cant find the css/image) and if i do it through static_file anyone can go to that link and view the css/image (IE `www.mysite.com/css/css.css` or `www.mysite.com/image/image.png`). Is there any way to get around this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for a webbrowser to be able to download and render the css or image, it will either have to be part of your page (where people can view it by viewing the source of the page) or accessible at a URL.

So if you're trying to get around people being able to look at just your css or just your image, the answer is that there's no way around it.

Comment: +1 and if you want to hide your CSS, you should consider what you are really trying to accomplish and why (aside from Sam's point that it simply can not be done without breaking the page).

Answer (score 0):

see how to route to static files in bottle in the documentation, here: http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#tutorial-static-files